# Photoshop: Shortcut for swapping foreground and background colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

There surely is a shortcut in photoshop that allows me to swap foreground and background colour. In case you don't know what I am talking about, these are the two swatches in question:

[image: photo showing photoshop UI with foreground and background colour swatches highlighted]

If someone knows said shortcut I would be very grateful if he / she could tell me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can swap foreground and background color with <kbd>X</kbd> key. Also, you can revert foreground and background colors to default (black and white) with <kbd>D</kbd> key - it's very handy when working with masks.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut for swapping the foreground and background colour is the <kbd>X</kbd> key on both Windows and macOS.