# Background color changing instead of foreground

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, shortcuts

I recently imported shortcuts to Photoshop, but whenever I change color it's the background one that keeps changing. It's incredibaly annoying when I draw. The obvious answer would be to delete the shortcuts, but I do like them a lot and it would take forever to change them all manually. Does anyone know how I fix this? I couldn't find anything where the shortcut-menu was.

Comment: *how* are you changing colors?? Holding the Alt key down with the eyedropper picks up a color for the background.. perhaps your Alt key is stuck.

Comment: "X" key. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99863/photoshop-shortcut-for-swapping-foreground-and-background-colour

Answer (score 1):

a wild guess: you accidentally clicked the background color icon in the `Color` panel

[image]